# Error 500 when trying to query getActivitiesByInterval route of Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I successfully retrieved a Microsoft Graph token with clientCredentials, but when I try to query the getActivitiesByInterval route (for a SharePoint site) I am receiving an HTTP 500 :

```
    "code": "generalException",
    "message": "The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error."
```

The application I registered has the following rights (Application) on Microsoft Graph (Files.Read.All, Files.ReadWrite.All, Sites.Read.All, Sites.ReadWrite.All, User.Read.All).
If I do exactly the same query with a token retrieved from graph explorer I received an HTTP 200 with the content I ask for.

The token I am using seems correct as I can retrieve the users on the Microsoft Graph without having an HTTP 500.

The code I am using to do the request is the following (it's an Azure Function with a Microsoft Graph binding to get the token):

```
[FunctionName("SharepointSitesViews")]
    public static async Task Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *", RunOnStartup = true)]TimerInfo myTimer, 
                                 [Token(Identity = TokenIdentityMode.ClientCredentials, IdentityProvider ="AAD", Resource = "https://graph.microsoft.com")] string graphToken,
                                 ILogger log)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", graphToken);
        var response = await client.GetAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/****MySiteId*****/getActivitiesByInterval?startDateTime=2018-09-12T09:59:19.817Z&endDateTime=2018-12-11T00:00:00.000Z&interval=day");
        var me = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
```

The same code with the url "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users" returns a 200.

I have also reproduce the same 500 error using postman :

```
GET /beta/sites/****MySiteId****/getActivitiesByInterval?startDateTime=2018-09-12T09:59:19.817Z&amp; endDateTime=2018-12-11T00:00:00.000Z&amp; interval=day HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.microsoft.com
Authorization: Bearer *****myToken****
cache-control: no-cache
```

Comment: Could you share more of your code here (ommitting client ids etc.) So we have more to work with?

Comment: I have just edited my question with the code. Do you need more information ? I find it strange that it works fine for users and not for getActivitiesByInterval, especially as I have the correct  roles on my token and I receive a 500 and not a 401/403.

Comment: I also tried using delegate rights and it works fine. Only clientCredentials seems to have an issue.

Comment: @JeremyThakeMSFT Do you have any clue about this one ? Is this a known bug of this route and if so is there a way for me to report it ?

Comment: When you break open your token in https://jwt.ms/ do the scopes you say are there there?

Comment: Yes there are.Here is what I get : 
`"roles": [
    "Application.ReadWrite.All",
    "Sites.Read.All",
    "Sites.ReadWrite.All",
    "Files.ReadWrite.All",
    "User.Read.All",
    "Files.Read.All"
  ],`

Comment: Have you confirmed that your url is correct for other operations on the site? e.g. can you get back the Site Title ok? Its just the getActivitiesByInterval operation that is failing?

Comment: Yes @JeremyThakeMSFT. I can retrieve correctly the site title. I only encountered  the internal server error on the getActivitiesByInterval operation for now.

Comment: OK let me reach out to the PM and get them to help here.

Comment: sorry i dropped the ball here. did this error get resolved?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I contacted Microsoft support through my company Azure subscription to get this solved but the ticket was closed by Microsoft with the reason "the solution for this issue is beyond our scope". I don't know if it was a mistake of the support or not but I haven't heard from them since despite my emails.

So I don't really know what to do, I have a project that needs to use the getActivitiesByInterval operation but is stucked because of this. If you have any idea how to proceed to progress on this issue, that would be great :).